# Android Relative Layout with an ImageView moving when app is reopened/changed activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm facing a problem with a RelativeLayout. Basically it at the first launch of the app is ok, all the ImageViews stay in the correct position. If i reload the app (without killing it from background) or i move to another activity (like About) and i get back, one imageView get distorted and moved from the original position.

I'm trying to use those two attributes but apparently they work as expected only when i don't reload anything.

`android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"`
`android:layout_marginEnd="70dp"`

Here there is the code of the layout. The last imageView is the one affected by this strange issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/welcome_title"
        android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_reg" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/welcome"
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@color/textSecondaryColor"
        android:text="@string/welcome_description"
        android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_reg" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_below="@+id/description"
        android:id="@+id/apply"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/apply_skin"
        android:textColor="@color/textPrimaryColor"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:cornerRadius="@dimen/button_round"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_play"
        app:iconTint="@color/textPrimaryColor"
        app:strokeColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:strokeWidth="@dimen/button_stroke"
        android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_reg"
        android:onClick="applySkin"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_below="@+id/apply"
        android:id="@+id/hide"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_hide"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_ripple1"
        android:onClick="hideAppIcon"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_below="@+id/apply"
        android:id="@+id/rate"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_rate"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_ripple1"
        android:onClick="rateApp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_below="@+id/apply"
        android:id="@+id/information"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="70dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_info"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_ripple1"
        android:onClick="startAbout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think your problem has relevancy to MaterialButton component ,change it and test your app again , before it clean project and launch app again

Comment: @miladsalimi thanks for the answer. Just tried and it didn't work.